# How Can I use a Switch Statement to Convert a Word to the ICAO Alphabet?

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement

I am attempting to write a program that converts a word inputted by the user into the International Civil Aviation Organization alphabet that must use a switch statement rather than a series of if statements. I was able to make this work for a single-character input, but when I attempted to modify the program to make it convert a series of letters by adding a while loop, the conversions became inaccurate.

As I explained above, I attempted to add a while loop to make the program read every character in an inputted word, which caused the problems.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Declare needed variables
    string word = " ";
    int count = 0;

    //Prompt user input
    cout << "Enter a word: ";
    cin >> word;

    while(count < word.length())
    {

    switch (word[count])
    {
        case 'A': case 'a': word = "Alpha";
            break;
        case 'B': case 'b': word = "Bravo";
            break;
        case 'C': case 'c': word = "Charlie";
            break;
        case 'D': case 'd': word = "Delta";
            break;
        case 'E': case 'e': word = "Echo";
            break;
        case 'F': case 'f': word = "Foxtrot";
            break;
        case 'G': case 'g': word = "Golf";
            break;
        case 'H': case 'h': word = "Hotel";
            break;
        case 'I': case 'i': word = "Indiana";
            break;
        case 'J': case 'j': word = "Juliet";
            break;
        case 'K': case 'k': word = "Kilo";
            break;
        case 'L': case 'l': word = "Lima";
            break;
        case 'M': case 'm': word = "Mike";
            break;
        case 'N': case 'n': word = "November";
            break;
        case 'O': case 'o': word = "Oscar";
            break;
        case 'P': case 'p': word = "Papa";
            break;
        case 'Q': case 'q': word = "Quebec";
            break;
        case 'R': case 'r': word = "Romeo";
            break;
        case 'S': case 's': word = "Sierra";
            break;
        case 'T': case 't': word = "Tango";
            break;
        case 'U': case 'u': word = "Uniform";
            break;
        case 'V': case 'v': word = "Victor";
            break;
        case 'W': case 'w': word = "Whiskey";
            break;
        case 'X': case 'x': word = "X-Ray";
            break;
        case 'Y': case 'y': word = "Yankee";
            break;
        case 'Z': case 'z': word = "Zulu";
            break;
        default: cout << "You did not enter a letter." << endl;
    }

    count++;
}
cout << "Phoenetic version is: " << word << endl;

return 0;
}
```

This code compiles in its current state, but does not give me the desired outcomes.

Comment: Do you really want to convert it in place? That seems like you're making it needlessly difficult.

Comment: Use two different variables - one for the word you are converting, and the other for the replacement for each letter. You are overwriting, and losing, the user's input on the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem you have is you change what `word` is every time you assign a ICAO phonetic value, e.g. `word = "Alpha";` You need to use a separate value to build the result string, e.g.

```
    //Declare needed variables
    string word = " ", phonetic {};
    unsigned count = 0;
    ...
    while(count < word.length())
    {
        switch (word[count])
        {
            case 'A': case 'a': phonetic += " Alpha";
                break;
            case 'B': case 'b': phonetic += " Bravo";
                break;
            ...
```

(**note:** the change to `unsigned` for `count` to prevent comparison between signed and unsigned values, and the use of `+=` to append each phonetic word to `phonetic` -- as well as the space added before each)

Now with the ICAO phonetic result stored in `phonetic`, you can output the result:

```
    cout << "Phoenetic version is:" << phonetic << endl;
```

Putting it altogether, you can do:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    //Declare needed variables
    string word = " ", phonetic {};
    unsigned count = 0;

    //Prompt user input
    cout << "Enter a word: ";
    cin >> word;

    while(count < word.length())
    {
        switch (word[count])
        {
            case 'A': case 'a': phonetic += " Alpha";
                break;
            case 'B': case 'b': phonetic += " Bravo";
                break;
            case 'C': case 'c': phonetic += " Charlie";
                break;
            case 'D': case 'd': phonetic += " Delta";
                break;
            case 'E': case 'e': phonetic += " Echo";
                break;
            case 'F': case 'f': phonetic += " Foxtrot";
                break;
            case 'G': case 'g': phonetic += " Golf";
                break;
            case 'H': case 'h': phonetic += " Hotel";
                break;
            case 'I': case 'i': phonetic += " Indiana";
                break;
            case 'J': case 'j': phonetic += " Juliet";
                break;
            case 'K': case 'k': phonetic += " Kilo";
                break;
            case 'L': case 'l': phonetic += " Lima";
                break;
            case 'M': case 'm': phonetic += " Mike";
                break;
            case 'N': case 'n': phonetic += " November";
                break;
            case 'O': case 'o': phonetic += " Oscar";
                break;
            case 'P': case 'p': phonetic += " Papa";
                break;
            case 'Q': case 'q': phonetic += " Quebec";
                break;
            case 'R': case 'r': phonetic += " Romeo";
                break;
            case 'S': case 's': phonetic += " Sierra";
                break;
            case 'T': case 't': phonetic += " Tango";
                break;
            case 'U': case 'u': phonetic += " Uniform";
                break;
            case 'V': case 'v': phonetic += " Victor";
                break;
            case 'W': case 'w': phonetic += " Whiskey";
                break;
            case 'X': case 'x': phonetic += " X-Ray";
                break;
            case 'Y': case 'y': phonetic += " Yankee";
                break;
            case 'Z': case 'z': phonetic += " Zulu";
                break;
            default: cout << "You did not enter a letter." << endl;
        }
        count++;
    }
    cout << "Phoenetic version is:" << phonetic << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** consider using `word.at(count)` instead of `word[count]` to enable bounds-checking while indexing individual characters -- here you are safe with `word.length()`, but in general `.at()` provides that additional level of validation)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/icaophonetic
Enter a word: apple
Phoenetic version is: Alpha Papa Papa Lima Echo
```

Look this over and let me know if you have questions.